# getting capistrano to restart delayed job v. 2.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

really sorry if this is obvious or covered here - have been searching
endlessly and can't get the answer clear.

i am using dj gem 2.0.3 (collective idea) // rails 2.3.5.

dj working great locally using **rake jobs:work**. but ...

```
script/delayed_job
```

does not work. i seem to recall searching and finding this is a
version issue ...req > 2.0.3 > rails 2.3.5 ...not 100% clear on this tho.

```
-bash: script/delayed_job: No such file or directory
```

so i want to setup capistrano and have examples using the script tasks
-- but am unsure how to do this with the rake tasks, or how to
get the script/delayed_job tasks to work.

thanks for any tips ...would be hugely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to ensure the path is set correctly when executing a command. Here's an example:

```
  desc "Start delayed_job"
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} script/delayed_job"
  end
```

Comment: thanks ...but when i try script/delayed_job from my app's root, i get no such file or directory.

Comment: Hmm. Can you tell if the script exists in the release directory? Are the permissions correct?

Answer (score 0):

To create script/delayed_job run 'rails generate delayed_job'